# relationship between rospy.init_node and rospy.Publisher?

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More specifically, lets say the command

```
rospy.init_node('topic_publisher')
```

creates a node with the name `topic_publisher` and then I state something like:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('/counter', Int32, queue_size=1)
```

my question is: how does that node `topic_publisher` know anything about the pub object?  the pub object does not input the node name so how does it know which node is publishing it? Is it because its in the same executable file? THe system somehow knows anything after `rospy.init_node` is related to this node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269630/relationship-between-rospy.init_node-and-rospy.publisher?/) by [badrobot91](https://answers.ros.org/users/31708/badrobot91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-26**:
I was trying to write this as an answer but I don't feel like I have a complete understanding of everything to do so I'll leave this as a comment.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-26**:
Basically, the node doesn't know about the topics (topics can be registered before node instantiation). When created, topics register themselves with Master and have their names resolved depending on whether they're private or global.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-26**:
So, `topic_publisher` doesn't know about the `/counter` topic because the topic is registered with ROS Master (which in turn keeps track of all nodes, topics, and much more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although on the tutorial [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) doesn't answer your question, we can see that our executable only can publish after call `rospy.init_node`, as you can see:

- The next line, `rospy.init_node(NAME, ...)`, is very important as it tells rospy the name of your node -- until rospy has this information, it cannot start communicating with the ROS Master.

When we try to publish without calling `rospy.init_node`, the following exception is raised:

- `rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?`

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Do you mean "publish" instead of "public?"

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-08-29**:
Yes ;)
Fixed. Thanks!